# js events not firing in webpack built react application

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-5

Spoiler: I am leaning towards a Webpack issue rather than React (since with a plain React app, taken straight form `create-react-app` things work). But still, it only happens with React...

The main issue is that a simple event (e.g. `onClick` is never getting executed), this extends to no js being used (accordions, complex nav behavious, etc.). So the following does not work:

```html
<button onClick={() => alert("TEST YEAH!")}>Click Me!</button>
```

Neither does it when using the `Button` component of libraries such as `react-bootstrap` or `semantic-ui-react` (tested in both).

The webpack config looks like:

```json
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.js"),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: ["babel-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "./bundle.js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

The *package.json* is:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.2",
    "eslint": "^7.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.19.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
```

You can find the minimal example in [here, in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-firefly-kqmfo). Just click the button and see that there is not alert being shown. In addition, there is some commented code for an `Accordion` component, which obviously does not work.

I was wondering... any tips on why is this happening? Some of my thoughts were the binding of the function, the injection of the code (but the `alert` appears in the *bundle.js* file)... Thanks in advance!

[EDIT]
**SOLUTION**

Remove the bundle inclusion in the main html. Since it is added automatically, it was being added twice and causing problems.

```
- <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same issue, please check the `index.html` file and remove the `script` tag.
If you are using the `html-webpack-plugin`, the script tag will be added to the html file automatically.

Comment: Removing the script related to the webpack bundle worked like a charm.