# react-dom-development: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am building my very first own React-App from scratch without using create-react-app.

While the components that I have written so far seems to work, the DevTools is showing the following error:

```
react-dom.development.js:24151 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
at startWorkOnPendingInteractions (react-dom.development.js:24151)
at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22658)
at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22288)
at eval (react-dom.development.js:11327)
at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468)
at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276)
at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11322)
at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11309)
at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21888)
at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:25477)
```

I tried to install the React Developer Tools Extension for Chrome but nothing changed.

Also, the page is not directing to the selected path. Let's say I select 'Login' from the Navbar and the URL is changing to 'http://localhost:3000/Login' but the page is not rendering the new path automatically, I have to press F5.

Here is the webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: "./src/index.html",
})

module.exports = {
    entry: ["./src/index.js"],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/frontend"),
        filename: "[name].js",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
    },
    
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        historyApiFallback: true,
      },

    plugins: [htmlPlugin]
};
```

and the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "StockApp.Frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack serve --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.6",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.38.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
}
```

the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <title>React App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script src="static/frontend/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the folder structure:

[image]

****EDIT:****

I was able to fix my problems by adding 'contentBase' to the devServer object within the webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: "./src/index.html",
    filename: "index.html"
})

module.exports = {
    entry: ["./src/index.js"],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/frontend"),
        filename: "[name].js",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
    },
    
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname,'./static/frontend')
      },

    plugins: [htmlPlugin]
};
```

The page is rendering correct and all the react components seems to work. However, now the following error message appears:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/static/frontend/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

If I change the path to '/main.js' within the index.html react is rendering perfectly and no error message, but the html seems not working because the onChange or onSubmit functions are not getting triggerd

```
return (
        <div className='container'>
            <label htmlFor='email'><b>Email</b></label>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Enter Email' name='email' onChange={e => console.log(e.target.value)} />
            <label htmlFor='password'><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type='password' placeholder='Enter Password' name='password' required />
            <button type='submit'>Login</button>
        </div>
);
```

Comment: Found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66246652/js-events-not-firing-in-webpack-built-react-application The problem was the HtmlWebpackPlugin, which creates the tag src="main.js" automatically. So the src-tag is not needed within the template index.html