# react + mui form onSubmit event not getting called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the mui box react component with the component property set to form and an onSubmit set to the submit handler I need to trigger.  I have a submit button at the end of the form.  Whenever I click on the submit button it seems as if the form is submitting a get request as I see the form fields in the querystring but I am not seeing the submit handler get called.  I added the e.preventDefault() in the handler and added a console.log and a debugger statement, none of which are ever reached.  Also, the onChange handler I have on the textFields are not getting called either.  What could be causing this to happen?

handler:

```
const submitForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('We made it to the expected place.');
    debugger;
  }
```

Form:

```
<div>
        <div className="w-100">
          <Container>
            <h1 className="text-center">Login</h1>
            <Box className="card loginUI" component="form" autoComplete="off" onSubmit={submitForm}>
              <div className="card-body">
                <div className="formFlexContainer">
                  <div className="formInput">
                    <TextField className="w-100" id="userName" label="Username" variant="standard" name="userName" onChange={e => {console.log('text change 1'); setUsername(e.target.value)}}/>
                  </div>
                  <div className="formInput">
                    <TextField className="w-100" id="password" label="Password" variant="standard" name="password" onChange={e => {console.log('text change 2'); setPassword(e.target.value)}}/>
                  </div>
                  <div className="formInput d-flex justify-content-end">
                    <Button type="submit">
                      Login
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Box>
          </Container>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Hey, so the onSubmit for a button only works if you have a `<form/>` component. Read the documentation to clear it up

Comment: The mui Box component with the "component="form"" adds a form component.  When I look at the source, I am seeing a form element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add form tag in the parent element and and add onSubmit attribute to that ,

```
<form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
...
</form>
```

in this case , i used formik , but its not matter , you should add form , or you can delete `type=submit` from button and set onClick for button directly

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on this stackoverflow link: [js events not firing in webpack built react application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66246652/js-events-not-firing-in-webpack-built-react-application).  The issue was an extra reference to the bundle.js file that webpack was already adding by default.  Removed and the events began working.